# Datastax Devcenter 1.1 fail to start

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I'm using 64 bit Windows 8. It was fine yesterday, and it just failed to start. It shows the [loading screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTMja.jpg), but it just stop right there.

Anyone has the same problem? Any fix? It has happened to me twice with my old pc, which were using 32 bit Windows 7.

Comment: There should be a log file in \Users\<YourUserName>\.devcenter\logging that might provide some more information if you can check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I haven't heard of this issue before, here's something that will hopefully fix the issue:

1. find a directory called `.devcenter` in your user directory (that should be `\Users\<youruser>`)
2. move this directory to a different location
3. start DevCenter

If this doesn't work:

1. in the same `\Users\<youruser>\.devcenter\logging` folder find the `log.txt` file; you might be able to see the root error
2. there is a newer version available (1.1.1)

Comment: I had a similar problem with 1.3.1. In addition to deleting `.devcenter`, I had to also delete `.eclipse` in that same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Some time this can be due to Java version. For me it was failing because I was using **Java 9**. It worked fine after downgrading to **Java8**. Confirm compatibility of your devcenter and java