# Datastax DevCenter fails to start

Tags: cassandra, datastax

DevCenter 1.5.0 won't start, even though it was working a few days ago. I have already tried as suggested by the answer to this question : [Datastax Devcenter 1.1 fail to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443521/datastax-devcenter-1-1-fail-to-start)

However it didn't work for me. It did lead me to think it might be due to having updated to Eclipse Mars Yesterday, perhaps?

Any ideas would be great. Thanks in advance.

In response to the comments below I am running windows 7. Also I just realised that even though my JAVA_HOME is set correctly I am gettng this error when I run java -version:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\username>java -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

**Update :** I fixed the java -version issue above by removing java.exe from C:/Windows/System32/ . But DevCenter is still not working.

Comment: what OS are you running?

Comment: Have you been able to find the log? Can you check what java version is on your system? The most probable cause I can think of is that the OS and the downloaded version of DevCenter are unmatched 32b - 64b. (check your OS and then make sure you download the corresponding DevCenter version)

Comment: Edited the answer above.

Comment: There should be a DevCenter log file under your home directory, e.g. c:\Users\<user-name>\.devcenter\logging\log.txt. And possibly another located at c:\Users\<user-name>\.devcenter\.metadata/.log. One of these may contain clues as to the underlying problem.

Comment: I got same error with 64 bit version, but found 32 bit version working on my machine although I have 64 bit processor.

Answer (score 1):

OS: Windows 10 Pro
Dev Center - 1.6.0 (downloaded as zip. to run, we need to unzip and it's ready to go)

Today I faced a similar problem and was able to resolve by deleting/uninstalling the current Dev Center and re-installing. When you delete manually, make sure you delete the .devcenter folder. You will then have to reconfigure the connection(s) that you were using.

-Regards

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs on my computer. it's was resolved.
do you make sure setup python 27 and java sdk 8u ? if was set up and it's not running you can check previous version 1.5

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).